# How to see MongoDB hosted via AWS DocumentDB when using mongosqld on AWS EC2

Tags: mysql, database, mongodb, amazon-ec2

**Goal**

I am trying to use MongoDB's BI Connector for Tableau, aka `mongosqld`.  I have version 2.10, so here are the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/master/reference/mongosqld/).

My long-term goal is to host mongosqld as a service on an AWS EC2 instance, and host MongoDB on AWS DocumentDB.

**Background**

A **successful** set of baby steps was:

1. Host MongoDB in a Docker container on my local machine via [mongo](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) image
2. Manually run `mongosqld` on my local machine, without a schema
3. Connect to it via `mysql` from my local machine

This works fine, I could see all of the databases via `show databases;`

My next set of steps was:

1. Host MongoDB in AWS DocumentDB
2. Host `mongosqld` on my EC2 instance at address `0.0.0.0:3307`, without a schema
3. Enable TCP comms on port 3307 and 27017
4. Connect to it via `mysql` from my local machine

When I use mysql shell's `show databases;` command, I **cannot** see my databases, only `information_schema` and `mysql`.

**Question**

Given all of this information, **does anyone here know what might have gone wrong**?  I am currently at a loss for what to try next.

Comment: I had posted in `mongo-db.slack.com`, and was pointed to this article: https://www.mongodb.com/atlas-vs-amazon-documentdb/compatibility.  Supposedly, the problem was with AWS DocumentDB not completely implementing MondoDB's API.  I had to do something entirely different